# How do you get HTML to adjust to SVG scaling

Tags: html, svg, scale

When I scale an SVG using the scale transform, the surrounding html does not respect this scale and fails to adjust its size.

I have the following SVG:

```html
<div>
    <svg height="300" width="300" viewbox="0 0 300 300" transform="scale(1.55)"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" version="1.1">
        <circle r="150px" cx="150px" cy="150px" fill="orange"/>
    </svg>
</div>
<div>
    <svg height="300" width="300" viewbox="0 0 300 300" transform="scale(1.55)"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" version="1.1">
        <circle r="150px" cx="150px" cy="150px" fill="green"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

For some reason the surrounding html doesn't adjust for the scaled up Svg.

All my testing so far has been on chrome and using primarily Svg declared in millimeter units.

When tested, the above example with the scale transform, the two circles overlap.

Without the transform they do not.
I want them NOT to overlap when scaled.

How can I get the Html to correctly adjust with the scaling of Svg?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have set fixed `height` and `width` and fixed pixels for your `svg`.
You have to change the properties of your `svg` and the actual circle path to correct it like in my example.

the `transform` property is something you don't need here in my opinion!

Try to change that and your HTML will surround like you want.

```html
 <div>
     <svg height="100" width="100" viewbox="0 0 200 200"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" version="1.1">
     <circle r="100px" cx="100px" cy="100px" fill="orange"/>
     </svg>
 </div>
 <div>
    <svg height="100" width="100" viewbox="0 0 200 200"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" version="1.1">
    <circle r="100px" cx="100px" cy="100px" fill="green"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**That should do the job!**

Comment: Yes I have seen there is a difference in the way scaling is handled between Firefox and chrome, which adds even more complexity to my question. I originally used Chrome. Neither browser does the job as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that, in SVG 1.1, I believe it wasn't properly defined how a `transform` attribute behaved when placed on a root `<svg>` element.

In SVG2 it has been. The behavior is defined in the [CSS Transforms specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-property).

Chrome seems to have implemented that, but Firefox hasn't yet done so for SVGs.  The behaviour in Chrome seems correct. `transform` on `<svg>` elements behaves the same as an HTML element (see example below).

```html
<div>
    <svg height="300" width="300" viewbox="0 0 300 300" transform="scale(1.55)"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" version="1.1">
        <circle r="150px" cx="150px" cy="150px" fill="orange"/>
    </svg>
</div>
<div>
  <div style="width:300px; height:300px; background-color:green; border-radius:50%; transform:scale(1.55)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. At least not in chrome. The viewbox gets bigger but everything inside remains at the original scale. This may be because in my actual SVG I use millimeter units.

Comment: My example was intended to show that SVGs are behaving the same as other HTML elements with a transform.  That's all.